# Store lower 16 bits of each AVX 32-bit element to memory

Tags: intrinsics, avx, avx2, narrowing

I have 8 integer values in an AVX value `__m256i` which are all capped at 0xffff, so the upper 16 bits are all zero.

Now I want to store these 8 values as 8 consecutive `uint16_t` values.

How can I write them to memory in this way? Can I somehow convert an `__m256i` value of 8 packed integers into a `__m128i` value that holds 8 packed shorts?

I am targeting AVX2 intrinsics, but if it can be done in AVX intrinsics, even better.

Comment: Using `_mm256_packus_epi32` you can pack 2 `__m256i` registers into one but the results are shuffled. Alternatively, extract the upper half of one register and use `_mm_packus_epi32`.

Comment: When you say "lane", you mean 32-bit SIMD element?  Not one of the two 128-bit halves of an AVX / AVX2 vector?  In AVX terminology, that's the usual use of "lane", as in "vpermilps is an in-lane shuffle, but vpermd is lane-crossing".  And "there are no lane-crossing shuffles narrower than 32-bit until AVX-512".  I'm aware that in ARM NEON and maybe some other SIMD contexts, "lane" is used to mean "element", but generally not for x86.

Comment: With AVX2, use `_mm256_packus_epi32` + `_mm256_permutex_epi64` to fix up the in-lane behaviour of the packing, like @chtz said.  With AVX1, extract the high half of one vector and pack into a `__m128i`.  That would cost the same 2 shuffle uops but produce half the width of data output.  (Although it's good on Zen1 where YMM registers get treated as 2x 128-bit halves anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

With AVX2, use `_mm256_packus_epi32` + `_mm256_permutex_epi64` to fix up the in-lane behaviour of packing two `__m256i` inputs, like @chtz said.  Then you can store all 32 bytes of output from 64 bytes of input.

With AVX1, extract the high half of one vector and `_mm_packus_epi32` pack into a `__m128i`.  That would still cost 2 shuffle instructions but produce half the width of data output from them.  (Although it's good on Zen1 where YMM registers get treated as 2x 128-bit halves anyway, and `vextractf128` is cheaper on Zen1 than on CPUs where it's an actual shuffle.)

Of course, with only AVX1 you're unlikely to have integer data in a `__m256i` unless it was loaded from memory, in which case you should just do `_mm_loadu_si128` in the first place.  But with AVX2 it is probably worth doing 32 byte loads even though that means you need 2 shuffles per store instead of 1.  Especially if any of your inputs aren't aligned by 16.